# ini_set( 'memory_limit', '512M') - Syntax error - unexpected "M"?

Tags: php, wordpress, server, ini-set

I have some code in Wordpress that retrieves all Woocommerce product SKUs and is memory consuming (6000+ products)

So, at the start of my function I tried to increase the limit temporarily:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
```

The result:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'M' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')'
```

I'm looking for an answer why this is wrong and I could not find it.
Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: A shot in the dark here, did you try using double quotes ? (")

Comment: Looks like it solved the problem! No error in log. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP [ini_set()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) as follow.

```
ini_set("memory_limit","512M");
```

OR

You can also try to change the memory_limit using either a php.ini or .htaccess file.

php.ini

```
memory_limit = 512M;
```

.htaccess

```
php_value memory_limit 512M
```

You can add this code in `wp-config.php`

```
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '512M' );
```

Comment: I want to change the memory_limit only when specific function is running, so no php.ini/.htaccess.
Anyway, using double quotes instead of single solved the problem. Thanks!